# Linking a Model (ie. comment) to many other Models (ie. post, profile)

Tags: php, database-design, model-view-controller, laravel-4, orm

I am building a PHP application with Laravel where I have a `Comment` Model and many other models to which `Comment` can be attached to.

For example, a `Profile` can have many `Comment` but also a `Post` can have many `Comment`.

Should I split `Comment` in two models (`ProfileComment` and `PostComment`) or should I keep them together like this?

```php
class Comment {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('User');
    }

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Profile');
    }

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Post');
    }

}
```

If I keep them together, then on a database level how should I manage the `comments` table?

I was thinking about having the following columns:

```
integer: id - auto-incrementing id
integer: user_id - the user id
integer: foreign_id - profile/post id
varchar: type - which model? profile or post?
varchar: content - the actual comment
```

Is this the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use 1 table you will need to make Comment model morph.
if you don't want to use morph, make separated.

I think if you will use schema from your question, you will use morph.

I don't tkink where is need to make more tables, because all comments will have same structure (id, user_id (author), comment)

so in this case you will need just to make it morph (tagable).

Comment: Is my approach correct then? Because somehow I need to know which Model is the comment attached to.

Comment: if you use Morph, you will not have to worry about "attached to", because you will make something like this: Post::comments() or Profile::comments(). the rest will do him. in database you will have structure like:

id
user_id
comment
commentable_id
commentable_type